# Changing the colour of the input field focus using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am implementing an HTML input field where the user has to enter his email address.  I am also implementing validation on the same input field using JavaScript.

```js
function validateEmail() {
  var email = document.getElementById('EmailTextbox');
  var errorMessage = document.getElementById('ErrorMessageJumbotron');

  var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

  if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
    errorMessage.style.display = 'block';
    email.style.color = '#E54A49';
    email.style.border = "1px solid #E54A49";
  } else {
    errorMessage.style.display = 'none';
    email.style.border = "1px solid #949494";
    email.style.color = 'black';
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

#EmailTextbox {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #949494;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron" id="ErrorMessageJumbotron" style="display: none;">
    <div id="errorMessage">
      <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true">
                        &nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <span style="font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; font-weight: 500;">Please correct the marked fields.</span>
                    </i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--container-->

<div class="container jumbotron">
  <input type="text" onblur="validateEmail()" id="EmailTextbox" placeholder="E-mail address" class="form-control">
</div>
```

If the email is incorrect, the border of the input field is set to red and the user is prompted to enter a valid email address.  However, when the user clicks on the input field, the focus is coloured blue and I want it red for this particular case.  Otherwise, I want it to be blue as the default.

I have tried several approaches to try to change the focus colour using JavaScript but I did not manage to get it working properly.

Comment: The blue that you're seeing is not a `border`, but rather an `outline`. If you look closely, your border is still there. You can disable outlines by doing `input { outline: 0 !important }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of what you are trying to do, to help you achieve your end goal:

**HTML**

```
<input onblur="onEmailInputBlur(event)" placeholder="E-mail address">
```

**CSS**

```
input.is-invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
  outline: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
var invalidClass = 'is-invalid';

function onEmailInputBlur(event) {
    var email = event.target.value,
        elClassList = event.target.classList;

  elClassList.remove(invalidClass);

  if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
    elClassList.add(invalidClass);
  }
}

function isEmailValid(email) {
  var validEmailRegex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return validEmailRegex.test(email);
}
```

---

A JsFiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/ybaagysn/2/